# Move input cursor in console to next line

Tags: c#, multithreading, input, console, output

This is a program with two threads; one for output and one for input. (Where _ is the console cursor)

```
Please enter a number:
12_
```

While you're typing 12, output gets generated which clears the current line and writes over it, so this happens:

```
Please enter a number:
Output
_
```

How can I make it take the 12 which you're still entering and move it to the next line, so you don't have to retype it?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prog = new Program();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(prog.getInput);
            t1.Start();
            prog.otherThread();
        }

        public void otherThread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Output");
            }
        }

        public void getInput()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string msg;
                msg = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
        {
            int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
            for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowWidth; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, when you enter "Hello" and DON'T enter, after 3 seconds it will be overwritten by "Output". I want to move the "Hello" and the input to the second line before it gets overwritten.

Comment: You've already asked this question before.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111078/console-application-writeline-above-current-working-line

Answer (score 1):

I just found this [article](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-text-mode-games.html#Positioning_text) ([web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180424222501/http://broadcast.oreilly.com:80/2010/08/understanding-c-text-mode-games.html#Positioning_text)) where Cursor positions and modifications are discussed. I found it pretty straight forward.

The centerpiec of it would be:

```
      int left = Console.CursorLeft;
      int top = Console.CursorTop;
      Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work.

1. Make the string msg Global. Declare it outside all functions.
2. Now simply print it in the next line after you clear the previous line..

   class Program
   {
       string msg;

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Program prog = new Program();
       Thread t1 = new Thread(prog.getInput);
       t1.Start();
       prog.otherThread();
   }

   public void otherThread()
   {
       while (true)
       {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
           ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Output");
       }
   }

   public void getInput()
   {
       while (true)
       {

           msg = Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }

   public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
   {
       int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
       Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
       for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowWidth; i++)
       {
           Console.Write(" ");
       }

       Console.SetCursorPosition( 0, currentLineCursor + 1 );
       Console.Write(msg);
       Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: But you don't get it. Input isn't entered, it stays editable while output is printed....