# Keep input line always active in the bottom

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

I'm developing a CLI application with C# and it basically has a thread which reads data from a socket and prints to the screen. Out of the thread, there's a `Console.ReadLine();` line that should be used for client input. Problem is: everytime data is read from the server and print to the console, anything I was writing for the `Console.ReadLine();` gets lost because it ends up like this:

```
server message
server message
client messagserver message
server message
```

So, is there a way to keep the input line always active in the bottom, while data from the server is being print above it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111078/console-application-writeline-above-current-working-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you will need to use Console.SetCursorPosition to move the cursor to the bottom of the screen and back again when printing your server message.   You may also want to use ReadKey to capture a key at a time so you can manage where it's actually being printed, etc.   It's not exactly trivial to implement.   See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx as a starting place.

A package like https://github.com/Thraka/SadConsole  may be another approach.  If you checkout their demo video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZukjZIqDfJw&feature=youtu.be ) at about 2 minutes into the video it looks like they are doing exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to possibly handle this is to route all output through a thread-safe console writer so as to prevent multiple threads from writing messages concurrently which may result in overlapping messages on screen.

e.g.

```cs
public static class MyConsoleWriter
{
    static object _locker = new object();
   
    public static void WriteLine (string message)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (message);
        } 
    }
}
```

An improved version could possibly place all the messages into a `List<>` and write to the screen later via a different thread, thus avoiding the `lock` on the part of the caller each time.